# React table - format data to create subRows

Tags: javascript, react-table

I'm using [react-table](https://react-table.tanstack.com/) to create an [expandible table](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/examples/expanding).

In that example data are in this format:

```js
[
  {
    "firstName": "wheel",
    "lastName": "arch",
    "age": 29,
    "visits": 39,
    "progress": 87,
    "status": "single",
    "subRows": [
      {
        "firstName": "singer",
        "lastName": "paper",
        "age": 24,
        "visits": 35,
        "progress": 55,
        "status": "complicated",
        "subRows": [
          {
            "firstName": "professor",
            "lastName": "beam",
            "age": 22,
            "visits": 14,
            "progress": 84,
            "status": "single"
          }, {...}
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
  {
    "firstName": "elevator",
    "lastName": "contribution",
    "age": 26,
    "visits": 74,
    "progress": 28,
    "status": "relationship",
    "subRows": [
      {
        "firstName": "debt",
        "lastName": "honey",
        "age": 3,
        "visits": 31,
        "progress": 31,
        "status": "relationship"
      }, {...}
    ]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "cup",
    "lastName": "media",
    "age": 8,
    "visits": 77,
    "progress": 37,
    "status": "single",
    "subRows": undefined
  }
]
```

So an array of objects and each object has a property `subRows` that can be `undefinedd` or an array of objects.

I've a flat dataset, so an array of objects and I want to recreate the above structure grouping by a property.

For example, this is my dataset:

```js
const data = [ 
  {animal: 'cat', name: 'mu', year: 2016},
  {animal: 'cat', name: 'muji', year: 2021},
  {animal: 'cat', name: 'mine', year: 2021},
  {animal: 'dog', name: 'fido', year: 2000}, 
  {animal: 'hamster', name: 'gerry', year: 2020}, 
  {animal: 't-rex', name: 'dino', year: 2020}, 
  {animal: 'sheep', name: 's', year: 2019}, 
  {animal: 'sheep', name: 'sss', year: 2016}, 
]
```

and I would like that the `animal` column is expandible. How can I do?

I try `groupBy` by Lodash but obviously it's not the good method here.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const result = [ 
  {animal: 'cat', name: 'mu', year: 2016},
  {animal: 'cat', name: 'muji', year: 2021},
  {animal: 'cat', name: 'mine', year: 2021},
  {animal: 'dog', name: 'fido', year: 2000}, 
  {animal: 'hamster', name: 'gerry', year: 2020}, 
  {animal: 't-rex', name: 'dino', year: 2020}, 
  {animal: 'sheep', name: 's', year: 2019}, 
  {animal: 'sheep', name: 'sss', year: 2016}, 
].reduce(function (acc, obj) {
    const x = acc.findIndex((entity)=>entity.animal===obj.animal);
        if(x!== -1){
            acc[x].subrows.push(obj)
        }else{
    const xx= {'animal':obj.animal,subrows:[obj]}
            acc.push(xx)
        }
        return acc;
                    
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Can you explain how your answer fix the OP issue ? Please [edit] your question